# How to focus on element in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt

i have this class for my input textbox:

```
    class InputTextBox extends FlowPanel { 
      public InputTextBox(String labelText) { 
        super(); 
        Label label = new Label(labelText); 
        TextBox input = new TextBox(); 
        this.add(label); 
        this.add(input); 
        this.addStyleName("myBox"); 
      }


    }
```

How do I set focus on that textbox so when onmoduleload is called the cursor appears in the textbox?  Adding a member function seems to throw many errors.

```
      public void setFocus(boolean b) {
        this.setFocus(b);

      }
```

Comment: another question:  how do i reference the value of the textbox?  private InputTextBox newUser = new InputTextBox("Username");      newUser.getText() doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

You should add this block to constructor or onLoad method:

```
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Scheduler.ScheduledCommand() {
@Override
public void execute() {
    //call setFocus method here:
    input.setFocus(true);
}});
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a property field for you TextBox and in your setFocus method call *textBox.setFocus(true)*, or whatever you called your TextBox property.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like so

```
class InputTextBox extends FlowPanel {
    private Label label;
    private TextBox textBox;

    public InputTextBox(String labelText) { 
        super(); 
        label = new Label(labelText); 
        textBox = new TextBox(); 
        this.add(label); 
        this.add(input); 
        this.addStyleName("myBox"); 
    }

    public void setFocus(boolean focus) {
        textBox.setFocus(focus);
    }

    public String getText() {
        return textBox.getText();
    }
}
```

Use it like so

```
private InputTextBox newUser = new InputTextBox("Username");
newUser.setFocus(true); // Set focus
String value = newUser.getText(); // get text
```